# Redirect https request to internal http port

Tags: https, http-redirect, metamask, ganache

I am trying to set a domain (example.com) that will redirect the HTTPS requests to HTTP localhost:8545

I have tried the following configuration on apache (first attempt to listen on port 8082)

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
        ServerName example.com

        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset Off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8545
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8545

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The second attempt is the following on the proxy_conf-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset Off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8545
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8545

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But none of these seems to be working properly. What I need to achieve is to be able to access the local ganache client which runs on 0.0.0.0:8545, from mobile Metamask which requires HTTPS to connect

Answer (score 0):

After a few more tries, I fixed it by disabling the redirects from 8082 and the SSLProxyEngine on 443. So the configuration is as follows:

With **SSL**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

#       SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset Off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8545
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8545

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Without **SSL**

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
        ServerName example.com

        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset Off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8545
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8545

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```